# Place the cursor on next line with o <ESC> after putting something from clipboard in with "+p

Tags: windows, vim

Copy text not ending in a newline from somewhere to clipboard on windows with `ctrl c` and paste it into a text file (which is) being edited with `vim` (in console mode in `cmd.exe`) by `"+p`. E.g., an URL with right click "Copy Link Address".

Then, for the next clipboard content (copied in the meantime), to paste it on the next line you need to move your cursor there by `o <Enter> <Esc>`.

What is a  smarter way of doing this?

Take text which is ending in newline, e.g., a line copied by `yy`. Why is the cursor staying on the first character of the line indifferently if you paste it back by `p` or `P` ?

Comment: This question is perfectly within the scope of many other Vim questions. It could benefit from a rewrite, though.

Comment: agreed. Allthough the question seems very poor: what is Esc - o - Enter - Esc supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you doing?

After `"+p`, you are in normal mode, `<Esc>` serves no purpose here, `o` opens a new line for insertion below the current one, `<Enter>` inserts a carriage return so you are now two lines below and you hit `<Esc>` again to come back to normal mode, ready to paste more content.

I see it that way, with `bar` copied from some other program and `[]` to mark the cursor in normal mode and `|` in insert mode:

```
[]
```

`"+p`

```
ba[r]
```

`<Esc>o`

```
bar
|
```

`<Enter>`

```
bar

|
```

`<Esc>`

```
bar

[]
```

Is that what you do?

If your problem is with the `o<Enter>` needed to put the cursor two empty lines below you have many ways to optimize. I'd recommend a simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <F3> 2o<Esc>"+p
```

that puts you two empty lines below and pastes the content of the `"+` register there.

Or a smarter one that takes a `{count}` (`2<F3>`, `9<F3>`):

```
nnoremp <F3> :<C-u>execute 'normal! ' . v:count . 'o'<CR>"+p
```

Of course you can choose any key or key combination instead of `<F3>`.

Comment: I actually have to give my this a sharp rethink...what was I doing...

Comment: thanks for the nice illustration!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:map <F9> "+p<ESC>o<CR><ESC>
```

Use anything you like in place of `F9` as a key-binding.

Then just select text into your clipboard and hit `F9` (or whatever you've chosen as your key binding)

Comment: would a record maybe fit better? Does `:map` stay for good of does it disappear when vim closes?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'put' the content of a register directly in insert mode using {register}

So the keystrokes are:

```
a<C-r>+<CR><CR><Esc>
a<C-r>+
```

So you Enter insert mode with 'a', put the register '+' used for the clipboard then insert two line breaks, return to normal mode then you copy the second link and repeat the operation

Answer (score 1):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) offers specialized paste commands like `glp`, which pastes a register in a new line, even if the register contents is just text without a trailing newline character.

Comment: how well is your plugin maintained?

Comment: It has no open issues, and I regularly use it myself.